# Appending a child component in to HTML using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do something like this but in react. I have found solutions that talk about working with the props but none of them has worked for me.
Basically what I want to do is add child component to a parent node in this way but in React.... any ideas? thanks!

```js
function add(k){
  var div = document.getElementById("div-"+k);
  var elm = "<div style='background-color: red'>text </div>";
  div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", elm);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="div-0" style="background-color: blue">
      <div class="card ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add(0)">add A</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="div-1" style="background-color: green">
      <div class="card bg-primary">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add(1)">add B</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="div-2">
      <div class="card bg-primary">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add(2)">add C</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
  

</div>
```

Comment: this seams to be the long way to go about it. I would just do something like this in the component. create an array on each click and then... `{clicksArray.map(item => <div>test</div>)}`

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of appending the element to add to the children array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class MyColumn extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    const innerItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
      innerItems.push(<div style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>text </div>);
    }
    return (
      <div className="col-sm-4" style={{backgroundColor: this.props.bgColor}}>
        <div className="card bg-primary">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.add}>add {this.props.name}</button>
        </div>
        
        {innerItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  add() {
    this.setState(state => ({ count: state.count + 1 }));
  }
}

const row = (
  <div className="row">
    <MyColumn name="A" bgColor={"blue"} />
    <MyColumn name="B" bgColor={"green"} />
    <MyColumn name="C" />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(row, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container" id="app">



</div>
```

Comment: well... this is exactly what i need!  i only have to do some change and it will work... really appreciate it!  thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A bit long way. Is this what you are looking for ?

```
<div className="row">
        <Column data="A" bgColor="blue" />
        <Column data="B" bgColor="green" />
        <Column data="C" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2: Using hooks**

```js
function Column(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  let newElements = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    newElements.push(
      <div key={i} style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        text
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div
      className="col-sm-4"
      style={{ backgroundColor: props.bgColor }}
      onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
    >
      add {props.data}
      {newElements}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**UPDATE: to create multiple elements on click**

```js
import React from "react";

class Column extends React.Component {
  state = {
    addElementClicked: false,
    clickedCount: 0
  };
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      addElementClicked: true,
      clickedCount: prevState.clickedCount + 1
    }));
  };
  getChildren = () => {
    let content = [];
    console.log(this.state.clickedCount);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.clickedCount; i++) {
      const newEl = (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} key={i}>
          text
        </div>
      );
      content.push(newEl);
    }
    return content;
  };
  render() {
    return this.state.addElementClicked ? (
      <div
        className="col-sm-4"
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.bgColor }}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        add {this.props.data}
        {this.getChildren()}
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="col-sm-4"
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.bgColor }}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        add {this.props.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Column;
```

Following will create only one child

```js
//Column.js
import React from "react";

class Column extends React.Component {
  state = {
    addElementClicked: false
  };
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      addElementClicked: true
    });
  };
  render() {
    return this.state.addElementClicked ? (
      <div
        className="col-sm-4"
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.bgColor }}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        add {this.props.data}
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>text</div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="col-sm-4"
        style={{ backgroundColor: this.props.bgColor }}
        onClick={this.onClick}
      >
        add {this.props.data}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Column;
```

Comment: This is very close! But not quite the same as the original. Your solution only adds one `<div style="background-color: red">text </div>`, not multiple if the button is clicked more than once. Should be an easy change!

Comment: yeah, a bit close... anyways thanks for your time! I really appreciate it!